# spring annotation configuration issue

Tags: annotations, spring

I don't know why spring 2.5.6 keeps complaining, but I don't have any "orderBy" annotation.

```
2009-10-10 13:55:37.242::WARN:  Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersiste
nceAnnotationProcessor': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'order' of bean class [org.springfra
mework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Bean property 'order' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the re
turn type of the getter?:
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'order' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Bean propert
y 'order' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:801)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:651)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:78)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
```

or even when I swap to use lower version spring 2.5.1, it's still complaining:

```
2009-10-10 13:57:56.062::WARN:  failed ContextHandlerCollection@5da0b94d
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:366)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:366)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:230)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:183)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.determineContextClass(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:243)
```

If I do not use annotation, it works fine. No problem at all,

Everything happened after this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:component-scan base-package="demo.dao">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
    </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

and I am sure my spring is configured properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- For mail settings and future properties files -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Check all the beans managed by Spring for persistence-related annotations. e.g. PersistenceContext -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <!-- jpaVendorAdapter Hibernate, injected into emf -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}"/>
                <!-- Data Definition Language script is generated and executed for each run -->
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${jdbc.generateDdl}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!--<property name="hibernateProperties"> -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe something odd happening with the autowiring -- did you try removing autowire byName and do it manually?

Comment: the same thing happened again....after i remove the 'byName'

Comment: Please post the Model class mentioned in Exception `Invalid property 'order' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Bean propert
y 'order' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?` and also post ful stack trace

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when migrating `Spring` to a new version.
Look for stray *JAR*-files from old versions.
In my case it was a dependency introduced by `jaxws-spring` through `maven`.